# Quade test in R

Tags: r

I would like to perform a Quade test with more than one covariate in R. I know the command quade.test and I have seen the example below:

```
## Conover (1999, p. 375f):
## Numbers of five brands of a new hand lotion sold in seven stores
## during one week.
y <- matrix(c( 5,  4,  7, 10, 12,
           1,  3,  1,  0,  2,
          16, 12, 22, 22, 35,
           5,  4,  3,  5,  4,
          10,  9,  7, 13, 10,
          19, 18, 28, 37, 58,
          10,  7,  6,  8,  7),
        nrow = 7, byrow = TRUE,
        dimnames =
        list(Store = as.character(1:7),
             Brand = LETTERS[1:5]))
y
quade.test(y)
```

My question is as follows: how could I introduce more than one covariate? In this example the covariate is the Store variable.

Comment: The first step would be to create an R object that would allow testing and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but unfortunately I am unable to understand your proposal. Could you give an example? Thanks in advanced,

Comment: You are the one that is supposed to provide the example. The code above is just copied from the help page. You say you want to analyze something different. So produce an example (in R code or using `dput`) that has more than one covariate.